# How to make a j2me project in NetBeans 7.0?

Tags: netbeans, java-me, netbeans-7, java-wireless-toolkit

I have installed Netbeans 7.0 (in window xp SP3) and I also installed "Wireless Toolkit 2.5".

But when I open Netbeans

> File->New Project

then there is only option for Java SE and Java EE.

Not for Java ME.

I also try

> Tools-> Plugin -> and search for Java ME

but I was not able to find "Java ME".

Comment: Netneans 7.0 already having *Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0*. Just check on **Java platform** in the **Tools**. And let me, Is there j2me platform available or not?

Comment: Ya i knw that NetBeans 7.0 have JAVA ME features...but i didn't get that.. and i dont have JAVA ME SDK...should i have to download it ?

Comment: Have you checked in Java platform?

Comment: @bharath No there is No java ME platform in NetBeans-> tool option

Answer (score 3):

At first install 'Mobility' plugin for NetBeans IDE for J2ME development. You can do this from `Tools` > `Plugins` > (Select and install). Then DO this.. In netbeans, `Tools`>`Java Platforms`>Select `Add Platform`>Select `Java ME MIDP platform emulator` > select the one you installed now (Wireless Toolkit 2.5(location))

Comment: But When we install the netBeans then why it takes only jdk of 1.6 version......After installing the Java ME SDK What should have to do.....means should i have to set path or nont ?

Comment: The NetBeans IDE comes bundled with the latest Java ME SDK 3.0 which supports both CLDC and CDC development, but I had the same problem as yours, and I solved it by installing the java sdk from the link which I gave you.

Comment: @Shanky try that and say what happened.

Comment: No i don't get any JavaMe tool in my NetBeans7.0...There is only option for JAVA SE & JAVA EE projects.....

Comment: DO this.. In netbeans, Tools>Java Platforms>Select Add Platform>Select Java ME MIDP platform emulator > select the one you installed now.

Comment: @Sanjay, Netbeans 7.0 already having Java ME SDK. No need to download for this.

Comment: That was a mistake, sorry, edited! and please let me know if the new way helps!

Comment: @ sanjay I firstly uninstall the NetBeans 7.0 & Window toolKit 2.5.. Then Install the NetBeans 7.0 only .... And i follow your way but there was only J2SE option and in add option there was no Java ME MIDP platform emulator........

Comment: Again sorry :) Install 'Mobility' plugin for NetBeans IDE from `Tools` > `Plugins`, then do the rest, Tools>Java Platforms>Select Add Platform>Select Java ME MIDP platform emulator > select the one you installed now (Wireless Toolkit 2.5(location))

Comment: Ok now i am again installing the netBeans 7.0.1 for all....Lets hope it will work.....And if not....I will ask u again....thanks for feedback ...

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you didn't use the Java ME supported Netbeans bundle. [Download Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) with All(Its including Java ME) supported technologies and reinstall the Netbeans.

**Edit:** Netbeans 7.0 having Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0. If you want to integrate Sun Java Toolkit 2.5, Just follow the *@Sanjay* steps.

Comment: Ok now i am downloading NetBeans 7.0.1 for all..... i want to ask you which one IDE is good NetBeans or Eclipse.. And can we develope j2me in eclipse(I thihnk we should have to download EclipseME or not...)

Comment: I suggest if you developing Java ME mobile application, go with Netbeans. Its good one. For eclipse no need to use EclipseME. Just download [Eclipse pulsar for mobile development](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/pulsar-mobile-java-developers/galileosr1) and integrate Java ME toolkit.

Comment: Ok Thanks Mr. Bharath for ur Suggestions.... I hope After Installing this new .exe of NetBeans ...App will properly Run..

Comment: i had Download completly...but when i install this...It creates an error....and Installation abort....Now what i have to do now..

Comment: Also manually delete previous netbeans folder in program files. What error you are getting?

Comment: Ya I have completly removed it from program files also..... Whenever i try to install it shows a msg "Installer File is Corrupted.."