# Which one is best IDE of NetBeans to develope a j2me application?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me, ide

I am new in j2me. I had installed NetBeans 7.0.1 for J2EE and J2SE. 
Is there any IDE of NetBeans that contains a complete package of J2ME(including both CLDC & CDC).

Answer (score 1):

I have already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737898/how-to-make-a-j2me-project-in-netbeans-7-0) on your previous question. Netbeans contains all Java ME bundle(CLDC and CDC). For more info look on this article, [How to create a MIDlet application with NetBeans.](http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/01/02/j2me-tutorial-how-to-create-a-simple-midlet-application-with-netbeans/)

Comment: Ya i have installed NetBeans yesterday Twice. But every time "Installation Error" display.....If in case My NetBeans 7.0 will installed then are you sure that i don't have to installed anything extra.........Means that i can directly create my application..

Comment: Have you downloaded properly?

Comment: Hey its wonder.I have download again & dont uninstall the previous version & then install 7.0.1 and nonw it is running properly.